# TypeError: React__default.forwardRef is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg

All my codes worked fine yesterday, but

I got an error today in the morning.

Could you please help to find out why this error occurred?

I am using versions of

```
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.5.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"react-spring": "^9.0.0-rc.3",
```

Thank you,

[image]

Comment: Did you upgrade any of your packages?

Comment: @Jayce444 Yeah, I downloaded react-router-dom yesterday night, and after I got an error today, I upgraded react and webpack.

Comment: Ok so given the error comes from `react-spring` and it seems you have the latest version of it installed, possibly `react-spring` is not compatible with React v17. You may have to downgrade ur react and react-rotuer-dom again to keep using `react-spring`